# Map values are getting overridden while iterating through Map

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to fetch data from excel sheet using Apache poi jars. I have three rows and four columns in my excel. The actual data is in 2nd and 3rd row. 1st row is headers which I'm using as key for fetching the values. While I do this, the output I get always shows the 3rd row data. I have tried debugging it and observed that 2nd row data is getting overridden by 3rd row.

Here is my code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    loadExcel();
    
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> superMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
    
    Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < excelSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; i++) {

        int lastColnum = excelSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        for (int j = 0; j < lastColnum; j++) {
            System.out.println("reading excel column");
            String key = excelSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            String value = excelSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            hm.put(key, value);
        }
        superMap.put("MASTERDATA", hm);
    }

    for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> set : superMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(set.getKey() + " : " + set.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MASTERDATA : {Blood Group=test2bg, UserName=test2, Address=test2add, Password=test2pass}
```

My Data in excel:

```
Username | Password  | Address | Blood Group
test1    | test1pass |test1add |  test1bg
test2    | test2passs|test2add |  test2bg
```

I have tried putting the map into a superMap, but still no luck. Any suggestions / advise would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that the `key` is the same for all entries. It works as expected because HashMap can contain just distinct keys. They cannot be duplicated

Comment: Single key can contain only one value. Consider making that value of type which can internally store many values like List.

Comment: Since you're already Apaching... use the org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is at this line, where you put the same key for each row

```
superMap.put("MASTERDATA", hm);
```

you could use the row number, i.e your `i` var of the outer loop to make it variable and unique

EDIT

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> superMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();

for (int i = 1; i < excelSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; i++) {
    
    Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

    int lastColnum = excelSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    for (int j = 0; j < lastColnum; j++) {
        System.out.println("reading excel column");
        String key = excelSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        String value = excelSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        hm.put(key, value);
    }
    superMap.put("MASTERDATA_" + i, hm);
}
```

to get something like

```
MASTERDATA_1 : {Blood Group=test1bg, UserName=test1, Address=test1add, Password=test1pass}
MASTERDATA_2 : {Blood Group=test2bg, UserName=test2, Address=test2add, Password=test2pass}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eritrean for your answer. I have tried this, but doesn't help. I'm getting the output as - MASTERDATA_1 : {Blood Group=test2bg, UserName=test2, Address=test2add, Password=test2pass}
MASTERDATA_2 : {Blood Group=test2bg, UserName=test2, Address=test2add, Password=test2pass}

Comment: I overlooked that you initialize your map outside your loop. Move it into the loop. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are putting every row data in the same key in the map. In HashMap single key has one value. So every time it replaces the previous value of `MASTERDATA` key.

```
superMap.put("MASTERDATA", hm);
```

Maybe you need to use `List<Map<String, String>>` instead of `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` to store all row data as list. And also need to create map inside in the loop for not using same map reference again.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < excelSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; i++) {
    Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
    int lastColnum = excelSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    for (int j = 0; j < lastColnum; j++) {
        System.out.println("reading excel column");
        String key = excelSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        String value = excelSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        hm.put(key, value);
    }
    list.add(hm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya. I had tried your solution, but still it doesn't work. I'm getting as output - Blood Group test2bg
UserName test2
Address test2add
Password test2pass
Blood Group test2bg
UserName test2
Address test2add
Password test2pass

Comment: @Kaustubh Declare map inside, neither it will use the same map reference.Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same key twice, because value will be overwritten, but you can put map in your superMap after the loop. In that case you will have "masterdata" key and map with multiple pairs as a value